# Rails: redirect to current path but different subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I think this should be fairly easy but I'm not familiar with how it's done...

How do you write a before filter that would check if the current request is for certain subdomains, and if so redirect it to the same url but on a different subdomain?

Ie: `blog.myapp.com/posts/1` is fine but `blog.myapp.com/products/123` redirects to `www.myapp.com/products/123`.

I was thinking something like...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :ensure_domain

  protected
  def ensure_domain
    if request.subdomain == 'blog' && controller_name != 'posts'
      redirect_to # the same url but at the 'www' subdomain...
    end
  end
end
```

How do you write that redirect?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[ActionController::Redirecting#redirect_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to) allows you to pass an absolute URL, so the easiest thing to do would be to pass it one with something like:

```
redirect_to request.url.sub('blog', 'www')
```

Comment: Doh! The sub method is just the plain old ruby sub method... ok so after further experimentation this works but I have to use more of a regex to take care of it. The `request.url` object gives me enough to figure out the rest though, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

A simple choice to redirect from subdomain to subdomain would be the following

```
redirect_to subdomain: 'www', :controller => 'www', :action => "index"
```

This would be called on a domain name for example foo.apple.com would then go to www.apple.com

Answer (score 2):

An even simpler option without the need to do a string sub or specify the controller or action would be to use

```
redirect_to url_for(subdomain: 'www', only_path: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for this is

```
redirect_to dummy_rul(subdomain: 'subdomain')
```

Example:

```
redirect_to projects_url(subdomain: 'edv') it will redirect on below url

"http://edv.maindomain.com/projects"
```

"edv" is my subdomain

Answer (score 0):

With more recent versions of Rails you may need the allow_other_host: true option in redirect() to prevent an error from being thrown.