# Rails current_path Helper?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a Rails 3.2 application with the following routing conditions:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /de|en/ do
  resources :categories, only: [:index, :show]
  get "newest/index", as: :newest
end
```

I've a controller with the following:

```
class LocaleController < ApplicationController
  def set
    session[:locale_override] = params[:locale]
    redirect_to params[:return_to]
  end
end
```

I'm using this with something like this in the templates:

```
 = link_to set_locale_path(locale: :de, return_to: current_path(locale: :de)) do
   = image_tag 'de.png', style: 'vertical-align: middle'
     = t('.languages.german')
```

I'm wondering why there doesn't exist a helper in Rails such as `current_path`, something which is able to infer what route we are currently using, and re-route to it include new options.

The problem I have is using something like `redirect_to :back`, one pushes the user back to `/en/........` (or `/de/...`) which makes for a crappy experience.

Until now I was storing the locale in the session, but this won't work for Google, and other indexing services.

I'm sure if I invested enough time I could some up with something that was smart enough to detect which route matched, and swap out the locale part, but I feel like this would be a hack.

I'm open to all thoughts, but this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594155/rails-redirect-to-current-path-but-different-subdomain) suggests just using `sub()`; unfortunately with such short and frequently occurring strings as locale short codes, probably isn't too wise.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you are using the `:locale` scope, you can use `url_for` as `current_path`:

```
# Given your page is /en/category/newest with :locale set to 'en' by scope

url_for(:locale => :en) # => /en/category/newest
url_for(:locale => :de) # => /de/kategorie/neueste
```

Comment: Nice trick, I ended up writing this: `def current_path(options = {});    options = request.params.symbolize_keys.merge(options); url_for Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.path).merge(options)
  end` which felt overkilled!

Comment: You can also use `url_for` without any arguments.

Answer (score 6):

In case somebody looks here, you can use `request.fullpath` which should give you all after domain name and therefore, will include locale.