# Route path with locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

This is in my routes file:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|es/ do
  get "about" => "static_pages#about"
end
```

I already know that I can use about_path to get the path to the "about" route, but I want to know if there is a method that will return the "about" route and the current locale in this format:

```
/en/about
```

Comment: Are you able to use `url_for`? See [this StackOverflow Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10921999/567863) for details.

Comment: So I have to use two different methods?  I was thinking if there was a method that combined them.