# Route all subdomains to www

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url-routing, subdomain

Is there a way in Rails to re-route all subdomains to www?  For example, if someone enters https://blah.example.com/campaign/39/public it would route to https://www.example.com/campaign/39/public

blah can be changed to anything like https://google.example.com/campaign/41/public but it would always route to www https://www.example.com/campaign/41/public

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594155/rails-redirect-to-current-path-but-different-subdomain

Comment: in case of more than one url, dont forget to use meta canonical in html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to redirect any domain link to www.

You need to change your `conf` file as below For Apache2 and httpd

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blah.example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

And if you use nginx than use this

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    ...
}
```

Hope it will help you..